# Sylius PostgreSql migrations

Tags: postgresql, symfony, sylius, symfony-3.3

I want to develop my project with Symfony 3 + PostgreSql + Sylius.
But on installation stage I've got the error:

> Migration can only be executed safely on 'mysql'

My questions is has someone the PostgreSql installation database? Or migration would be the way better

Comment: I have the same question. Any update on this ?